# Faster Portfolio Optimization under rank 1 updates

Tags: portfolio-optimization, high-frequency

I was studying Markowitz portfolio optimization and had a question on the practicality of this in the setting of high frequency trading. Optimization seems like a cumbersome process. But at each tick the covariance matrix is updated only by a rank 1 update

$$\Sigma_{T+1} = \frac{p_{now} \cdot p^T_{now} + T \cdot \Sigma_T}{T+1} $$

Are there faster optimization techniques that utilize this rank 1 update structure and produce the optimal weights at $T+1$ by utilizing the optimal weights at $T$?

Also, along these lines, if I pass the earlier weights as an initial guess for the next time stamp, is the optimizer likely to perform faster?

Couldn't find anything in literature regarding this topic.

Comment: Do you believe that every tick meaningfully changes the covariance matrix. If not, then why bother doing it every tick

Comment: Perhaps not, but do you have an answer to faster optimization over rank 1 updates?

Comment: I just googled and there were many hits so I'm just putting one in here.  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8145125

Comment: I have seen this paper but couldn't get a full version. Could get only the first page. I think they are not talking about the same problem. They are talking about doing rank 1 updates to the Hessian to preserve PSD-ness when using iterative numerical solvers.

I think this isn't related at all to the original question.

Comment: but there were many other hits also. maybe use a more specific search expression than I used. I used something like "rank 1 update optimization problem".

Comment: I tried a few combinations on google but everything leads to faster rank 1 update and not faster optimization. Btw, the paper you suggested is around this topic

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_rank-one

Comment: Look for online algorithms. The optimization will often be easier with a good initial guess for a number of reasons. The documentation of the function you’re using should tell all about it.

Comment: @BobJansen Thanks for the suggestion!!
I had forgotten the term "online".
I guess that is the accurate term for CS people.

Comment: There should be some stuff on here about online algorithms. I even think one about covariance matrix updating but I haven't found it.

Comment: Hi: This sounds relevant possibly. https://www.aimspress.com/article/doi/10.3934/math.2022869

Answer (score 1):

Optimization requires $\Sigma^{-1}$. Updating inverse matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$ due to a rank-one (or low rank) update to $\Sigma$ is efficient with the [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula (rank-one update) or more generally the [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Ebindel/class/cs6210-f09/lec12.pdf) formula (low-rank update).

---

Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should.  I fully agree with the hesitancy expressed in the first @bob-jansen comment below your question.